# Can you change the orientation of the Unity launcher?

Tags: unity, 11.04, launcher

I was looking at 11.04 pre-Alpha and wondering if I can change the dock orientation. Does the pre-Alpha have this function? Is the idea being implemented as we speak? If not where can I propose this idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I move the Unity launcher?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/33605/can-i-move-the-unity-launcher)

Answer (score 9):

This feature request was [reported as a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/668415) recently, but the request was declined.

Mark Shuttleworth answered:

> I'm afraid that won't work with our broader design goals, so we won't implement that. We want the launcher always close to the Ubuntu button.

*See also: [OMG Ubuntu - Ubuntu Unity launcher won’t be ‘moveable’](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/12/ubuntu-unity-launcher-wont-be-moveable)*

Answer (score 4):

I've no idea whether this is being implemented or not (**edit:** see [fluteflute's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16184/can-you-change-the-orientation-of-the-unity-launcher/16316#16316) here), but:

- You can submit your ideas for ubuntu at [[image] **Ubuntu Brainstorm**](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/).

There isn't a proposal yet for your idea, so i suggest you add one. By the way, they are indeed being read by the Ubuntu developers.

Answer (score 1):

unity wont support changing the *launcher*(please dont call it dock) position afaik. it might have something to do with the fact that ubuntu button in the top left have a relationship with the launcher e.g. the icon will glow if there is pending notification in one of the running apps.

Comment: Why not? This is the real Dock, directly from *Step (http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/3/3b/NeXTSTEP_desktop.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

No, The position of the launcher is fixed (left) but and I wished to change the position too, so rather than changing I set it to auto-hide which is effectively good option (without using any external apps). The launcher when hovered overlaps the opened application rather than shrinking the size. So thats equally good. :)