# Can I move the Unity launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher

I can’t get used to the new Unity system. I’d like to move the left Unity panel to the bottom of screen (like Windows 7 – more similar is better).

But I can't find a way. Is it possible?

Comment: As of Ubuntu 16, the accepted answer should be [this one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/33605/can-i-move-the-unity-launcher/747825#747825).

Answer (score 107, accepted):

## 11.10

There is now an **unofficial Compiz Plugin** that allows you to move the Unity 3D (not Unity 2D) launcher from the left to the bottom.

[image]

*[Credit to WebUpd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/11/install-ubuntu-unity-bottom-launcher.html).*

In summary:

1. You can now peruse the source-code. Contact the maintainer with suggested fixes!  Remember this is unofficial and can & probably will have many bugs still to be ironed out.
2. Install the PPA - `ppa:paullo612/unityshell-rotated`
3. The packages to install are `unityshell-rotated libnux-1.0-0`
4. A new plugin *Ubuntu Unity Plugin Rotated* will be made available in CCSM
5. There is a likelihood of freezes on installation. If this occurs use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to start a TTY, login and restart lightdm with `sudo service lightdm restart`.  Rerun `ccsm` to enable the new plugin
6. This plugin replaces the official Unity Plugin.  You will obviously not receive further bugfixes from the Ubuntu development team - you will be reliant on the PPA maintainer to supply bug-fixes

**warning please see this [Q&A as to potential stability issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it) using CCSM**

---

Linked Questions:

1. [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)
2. [Source code](https://code.launchpad.net/%7Epaullo612/unity/unityshell-rotated)

Comment: @fossfreedom Can i restore the **Official Unity Plugin** incase i decide to revert back??( I use 12.04 now)

Comment: I've headlined the answer as 11.10 - it is applicable only to 11.10 (no 12.04 PPA as yet).  For 11.10 users - yes you can revert because the standard plugin exists in CCSM to be chosen (reactivated).

Comment: Well. Ok. This moves it to the bottom. What about the right side? I'd like it to be on the right the way like the Wharf Bar in AfterStep.

Comment: @Ivan - note - the answer is headlined 11.10.  Other answers for newer questions exist.  However you should note - right hand side launchers are not available unless you are using a right-to-left language such as arabic and hebrew.

Comment: This is a nice idea. But will it work in Ubuntu 15.04?

Comment: This answer pertains to a EOL release. Should it be kept?

Comment: @tim policy on ask Ubuntu is to keep answers not to delete stuff

Answer (score 106):

### 12.04 - 15.10

As of 12.04 you can ***not*** move the launcher, and there’s **no** official support for that.

**This is by design**, and so far, there are no Canonical plans to change that. Here’s a quote [from Mark](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/668415/comments/2) on [the bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/668415) for Ubuntu 11.04:

> I think the report actually meant that the launcher should be movable to
>   other edges of the screen. I’m afraid that won’t work with our broader
>   design goals, so we won’t implement that. We want the launcher always
>   close to the Ubuntu button.

I interpret that as a stand that a consistent design must be experienced as a Unity (pun intended), or it won't work at all.

While I personally disagree with Mark’s/Canonical’s decision *not* to provide a way to move the launcher (*please read my final note on this*), I do understand the design choice: it truly makes sense for it to be on the side and not at the bottom. Most users today have a widescreen monitor, and virtually all monitors for sale, specially for end-user consumer market, are widescreen too. That means the vast majority of users have lots of extra horizontal space (mostly underused), while vertical space is premium.

Most apps and websites do not use your whole screen width (check the large vertical background bars in both sides of screen of Ask Ubuntu, for example). But they *do* use the full vertical length (actually, they scroll 3, 5, 10 times your screen height). Meaning lots and lots of scrolling. And then you subtract title bar, menu bar, favorites bar, tabs bar, etc., all of them sucking up your precious vertical space. So adding the launcher on top/bottom would make things even worse, while there’s plenty of extra, “idle” horizontal space.

There is an ongoing, strong movement in app development, specially browsers, towards reducing the number of bars and merging them together. Think about how Firefox changed in this regard in the last few years. So it makes sense for an OS to do the same.

True, Windows’ panel is a well-crafted one… but the design choice of Unity to put it at side and not the bottom is a wise one, once you get used to it. And it’s worth doing so. Your mouse wheel will say thanks ;)

That said, some important notes:

- I am just expressing Mark’s/Canonical’s statements and point of view. While I do understand the design choice, and I do agree with a side launcher, I certainly do *not* agree with the decision of not being able to move it. But *I’m just a messenger. Don’t shoot the messenger*.
- There are unofficial, third-party packages that allow you to move the launcher. [This other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/72801/11015) covers that in great depth.
- You *can*, at least, have *some* control over the launcher in a multi-monitor setup:

[image: Unity launcher multi-monitor settings]

*(image edited from [Ubuntu Vibes](http://www.ubuntuvibes.com/2012/04/ubuntu-1204-precise-pangolin-released.html))*

Comment: If you’re wondering, the “Ubuntu button” (a.k.a. “[BFB](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10637790&postcount=6)”) mentioned by Mark in the quote is apparently a button that was [in the top-left of the screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Unity_2D_with_KDE.png) at the time of his comment. Now it is [on the launcher itself, at the top](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Unity_5.12_on_Ubuntu_12.04.png). Since it would thus move with the launcher, it no longer helps to justify Mark’s design choice.

Comment: On multi-monitor setups, the bar on the side is demonstrably inferior to on the bottom (provided the bar is on a screen that has another screen to the left of it, as the center screen in a 3-screen setup would). The launcher is now "out in space" and no longer enjoying the Fitts' Law infinite sized screen edge. Sticky edges attempt to make that edge a wider target, but it's still a poor substitute for a hard stop.

Comment: With regards to design, Usability and aesthetics. Although the "using the horizontal space" discours is interesting, the current taskbar is by far not a solution. Why? Simply because the icons are not really polished, sometimes not representative, and as there is no horizontal space for TEXT you cant have informative text.. for example "Google Chrome - 2 instances open" or if you're on Gmail: "2 New emails - Gmail". I guess Windows 8 are doing the horizontal space thing, but much much better.. Where do I raise these concerns?

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos: Not true: both number of windows and an arbitrary number can be shown for each icon in the launcher. First is represented by little white triangles at right side of each icon, and the arbitrary number can be seen in several applications (update manager, IM chat, etc). You can even have a mini-progress bar in each icon!

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos : as for the best place to discuss design issues (and questions, ideas, feedback), I think it would be the Ayatana mailing list, or their launchpad project page. (Ayatana is the Ubuntu Design project/Team for Unity & more)

Comment: It took me a week to understand that "these little arrows" (that you need a magnifying glass to see them) represent the number of the instances.. (and imagine I'm a UI designer..) Thanks for the mailing list, I'll do that.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane Also the wide display is not a justification neither, since you may be using auto hide panel as I do, so it does not stole no single pixel to other apps.

Comment: I have my primary monitor rotated so that it is vertical and so the launcher actually eats away precious space in the limited dimension, which is a shame.

Comment: @BurhanAli: I also have a sweet 24" monitor with pivot that I love to put in portrait mode, so I do share your pain and I also regret Mark's/Canonnical's decision. Autohide helps, but does not solve th issue. A placement option would surely make us "corner-case"  users way more happy :)

Comment: I use a similar setup to yours, just the monitor right to the laptop. I really would like to have a second unity bar on the right side of my main monitor. The distance to the left side of my laptop monitor is insanely long!

Comment: I have N monitors aligned horizontally: having them all interrupted by this launcher is horrible. option of removing it on N-1 is also suboptimal as I want launcher on every screen. at the bottom. where it would be natural and obvious and for god's sake this is linux we are supposed to be able to control things we are programmers not sheep. leave the "we have decided not to allow this" kind of crap for windows and macs. honestly.

Answer (score 51):

## 16.04 and later (Unity 7)

From 16.04 the unity launcher can be moved.

[image]

Copy and paste the following into a terminal:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher launcher-position Bottom
```

To reset it back to its side-position:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher launcher-position Left
```

Comment: Wow I didn't thought it would be that easy :p

Comment: Seems as if this requires 16.04, Unity 7 on 14.04 have no "launcher-position" setting. Thank you for posting the answer!

Comment: The users of 16.04 onwards should be also interests of using various methods to move the launcher to the bottom position listed in this post: [How does one move the Unity Launcher to the bottom in Ubuntu 16.04](http://askubuntu.com/q/760457/295286)

Comment: @fossfreedom how did you style your ubuntu like that? I like this style.

Comment: How about putting it to the right edge? Why isn't that possible?

Comment: @AlexanderPacha nope, "The provided value is outside of the valid range"

Answer (score 22):

You can't move the launcher from where it is. [Here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/668415/comments/2) is a comment from [Mark Shuttleworth](http://www.markshuttleworth.com/):

> I think the report actually meant that the launcher should be movable to
>   other edges of the screen. I'm afraid that won't work with our broader
>   design goals, so we won't implement that. We want the launcher always
>   close to the Ubuntu button.

As an alternative, you can use [Cairo-Dock [image: Install Cairo-dock]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/cairo-dock/):

> Cairo-Dock is a pretty, fast and customizable desktop interface. You can see it as a good alternative/addition to Unity, Gnome-Shell, Xfce-panel, KDE-panel, etc 
>   After 6 months of hard work, a new version of Cairo-Dock is available (Source: http://www.glx-dock.org/).

Other alternatives that offers you a launcher at the bottom of the screen: [Cinnamon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94201/how-do-i-install-the-cinnamon-desktop), [LXDE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44062/how-do-i-install-lxde-lubuntu), and so on.

This is a screenshot of my Cinnamon desktop (as you can see the launcer is at the bottom):

[image: Cinnamon desktop]

As you can see, *Linux is full about choices!*

Comment: The funny thing about that quote though,  is that it was made back in the day of Natty.  They've since moved the Ubuntu button onto the launcher itself,  making that argument null.

Comment: So now that the argument is null, is there a way, in 13.04+?

Comment: @digitalextremist: nope, and not up to 14.04.

Comment: Dude you're awesome!  This is so great that I don't even need sidebar.

Answer (score 15):

If you are using Ubuntu 16.04 you can run the following command in terminal to move the unity launcher to the bottom:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher launcher-position Bottom
```

If you want it in the default location (left of the screen), run:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher launcher-position Left
```

Answer (score 11):

You can also use Unity Tweak Tool to move the launcher to the bottom.

First install Unity Tweak Tool with the following line from a terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>)

```
sudo apt install unity-tweak-tool
```

after that you can open it from dash or command line.

You will be greeted by the following window where you need to access the **Starter** (called **Launcher** in english) tab (see arrow):

[image: unity-tweak-tool-1]

In the starter tab then you will see the option to move the Launcher to the bottom (see arrow in following picture):

[image: unity-tweak-tool-2]

Comment: The tab is called "Launcher" in English.

Comment: Included it into the answer, thank you. Thank you aswell for corecting my incredible bad grammar :))

Answer (score 4):

Another possible solution - via `dconf-editor` , the schema is `com.canonical.Unity.Launcher`

[image]

To install `dconf-editor` run `sudo apt-get install dconf-editor` in terminal , or find it in the new software center

Comment: It is not the option in ubuntu 14.04

Comment: @Pallavi  yes, because bottom placement of the launcher has been  added in 16.04  :)  Also , if you didn't notice , the question is tagged 16.04 , hence there would be no answers related to 14.04 in the first place