# Unity "Sidebar" - is it configurable/repositionable?

Tags: unity, launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I move the Unity launcher to the bottom of the screen like Windows 7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33605/can-i-move-the-unity-launcher-to-the-bottom-of-the-screen-like-windows-7)

I was reading the introduction to Unity and it says the launcher was made into a sidebar for convenience on widescreen monitors.  Is it configurable, say to move it along the bottom of the screen, for people like me who use a "widescreen" monitor in "Portrait" mode?

If not, this is a dealbreaker for me, I'm afraid.