# How do I install LXDE / Lubuntu?

Tags: desktop-environments, lxde, lubuntu

I want to install lubuntu on my current (pre-existing) Ubuntu Install because of it's light-weight footprint.

Can I preserve currently installed apps after installation?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

## For 11.10 and 12.04

For 11.10 and 12.04, you'll need to do this through a terminal.

Open up a terminal (<kbd>Super</kbd>, then type `Terminal` into the dash), then run the following:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop`

Or install via the Software Center:

[image: Install via the software center]

You will get asked to enter your password, and you will also be asked to choose between `LightDM` and `LXDM` - I suggest using `LightDM`.

Once that is done, log out, and then select `Lubuntu` as your desktop session:

[image]

Answer (score 14):

## For 10.04 and 11.04

Lubuntu uses the LXDE desktop enviroment, which is less resource intensive than GNOME2.
Other than that they are the same.

To install Lubuntu you need to do this:

[image]

Go to the Synaptic package manager and search for:

```
       lubuntu-desktop
       lubuntu-restricted-addons
       lubuntu-artwork
       lubuntu-core
       lubuntu-default-settings
       lubuntu-icon-theme
       plymouth-lubuntu-logo
       lubuntu-restricted-extras
```

(lubuntu-desktop is a meta package so it should install all the other packages) Install it and well...that's it.

Now whenever you login in GDM you can choose from Ubuntu and Lubuntu

You can search it on the Ubuntu Software Center as well.

Comment: @ Uri - Can I safely uninstall GNOME from there after I install lubuntu-desktop? Thanks for ur reply.

Comment: Applications you are using may need parts of GNOME as a dependency. I would rather **not remove GNOME** then.

Comment: @ Takkat - Can u pls elaborate? If don't uninstall & still I'm using lubuntu-desktop, will it show some problems? Thnx.

Comment: @Rahul: I've tried that once with 10.04 and did not encounter problems. However both, LXDE and GNOME will be regularly upgraded, and both will occupy their harddisk space (may be an issue if you are shot of capacity).