# How do I change my desktop environment to lxde?

Tags: lxde

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install LXDE / Lubuntu on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44062/how-do-i-install-lxde-lubuntu-on-ubuntu)

I'm running ubuntu 11.10 unity
my battery doesn't last more than 2 hours 
so i want to change from unity to lxde 
is it possible to install directly without formatting again?

if so can you give me instructions please

Comment: This question might be useful to you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/44062/how-do-i-install-lubuntu-on-ubuntu

Comment: You got two questions here - I've edited your question to clarify... its really a duplicate.  There are other similar battery life questions.  If you dont feel they are applicable to you, please post a new question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

[image: Install via the software center]

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lxde/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lxde
```

Not without risk, you could encounter troubles with broken packages...