# How to fix slow-performing machine?

Tags: performance

My laptop is a Compaq nx6110 with 1 GB RAM.

Before Ubuntu, XP was originally installed on it and was not too slow. But after I installed Ubuntu 13.04 (replacing XP) it is too slow.

Even YouTube videos are not played continuously though the net speed is sufficient. Also the headset is not detected.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: What amount of RAM do you have?

Comment: Try Lubuntu. 1 GB is not much RAM. See [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/83707/how-do-i-change-my-desktop-environment-to-lxde/83723#83723)

Comment: i have 1 Gb ram @Alvar

Comment: But your question states 1GB?

Comment: Take a look at my answer [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/309881/whats-the-best-operating-system-for-old-computer-linux/309884#309884).  Using Gnome classic made it even better.

Answer (score 1):

Install [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net). It's an official alternative version of Ubuntu that is designed for older PC's like yours.

Comment: can i use the software that are used in ubuntu

Comment: @user169886 Yes. Everything that runs in Ubuntu runs in Lubuntu too.

Comment: Also [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org) should work reasonably well

Comment: And you should opt in the html5 trial on youtube. Flash is resource hungry.https://www.youtube.com/html5