# What do I need to do to switch from Ubuntu to Lubuntu on a dual boot computer?

Tags: 11.10, dual-boot, lubuntu

I got a new laptop which makes my old one with a dual boot of XP and 11.10 redundant.  Everything has been moved over and this is a perfect chance to play around with variants.  I would like to replace the Ubuntu with Lubuntu but assume that if I just remove the Ubuntu partition to make room there will be issues with the existing grub.  Is there a way to do this?

Or as another possibility I could shrink the Ubuntu partition and install something in the empty space.  Will an Ubuntu based installer recognize what is going on and set up a triple boot as effortlessly as it does a dual boot?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install LXDE / Lubuntu on Ubuntu? ](http://askubuntu.com/questions/44062/how-do-i-install-lxde-lubuntu-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to delete the Ubuntu partition and re-install. You can install the [`lubuntu-desktop`](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/lubuntu-desktop) (click on link to install directly) package and use Lubuntu Desktop instead of Unity.

Look for the package in the Ubuntu Software Center and install it, after its done log off and on the screen where you insert your password for the user just select the new desktop environment.

[image]

You will even be able to select which login manager you want (`LXDM` or `Lightdm`) during the installation.

[image]

Trying to install Lubuntu side by side with Ubuntu and WindowsXP can lead to more confusion and its really use less since you can install the desktop on top of your current installation. Why have 2 based Ubuntu systems when 1 can do the same job using a different desktop environment?

You can even remove Unity if you are not planning on using it anymore later on. It can also stay there in case you need it, it wont slow down you computer having it installed.

Answer (score 2):

As you may know, you can try the various desktops either from the live desktop CD or by installing them.

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

You can make space with any number of tools, gparted is most popular. Run gparted from a live CD and resize your partitions.

When you install, install grub just as you did when you first install, and you will be able to triple boot, no problem is anticipated.

Comment: While for now I'm going with the desktop installation only. I may end up playing with a triple boot just as an exercise in the future. +1 for throwing in the Live option for future folks who stumble on the question.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely you can install Lubuntu side by side to windows XP and ubuntu and grub will show you three OS. However, Lubuntu will be most probably shown as  another ubuntu entry. If you want to try Lubuntu desktop environment you can also download and install the Lubuntu-core package using software center or synaptic. On login you can choose the desktop environment.Have fun.