# Uninstalling Gnome 3 and reverting back to Gnome 2?

Tags: 11.10, gtk3, gnome2

Is it possible to completely purge anything Gnome3 and completely revert to gnome 2 with the panel and stuff. I do not want to get suggestions on how to get to the `classic` session, I want to know how to uninstall the GTK3 stack from 11.10 and replace it with GTK2

I know Gnome is no longer maitaining Gnome2/GTK2 so, I know the concerns.. backward incompatability e.t.c

Comment: ... you might want to think how to structure your question as to not be a duplicate of this or the master "revert to gnome-classic" question (http://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic).  There is also a "mate-desktop" question (http://askubuntu.com/questions/87040/how-to-install-mate-in-11-10-and-above)

Comment: I tried to do this for a while too, but I eventually figured that I was trying to punch a hole in a brick wall.  Accept gnome3 or switch to xfce.  I have both running the way I want now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ubuntu 11.10 is built on the premise of the GTK+3 software libraries.  Therefore, removing GTK+3 will effectively mean no "ubuntu".  What you will be left with is a newer kernel and a few additional slightly upgraded packages.

If you are not interested in backward compatibility etc, then it would be simpler to start from a GTK+2/gnome2 based distro such as Natty and upgrade from that.

Thus, at a minimum - look to installing the 11.10 kernel - either from the mainline or compiling your own.

If the tenor of your question is simply that you don't like the gnome-classic option then personally I would look at similar gnome-2 workflow options such as [Cinnamon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94201/how-do-i-install-the-cinnamon-desktop) or excellent panel based options such as [LXDE/Lubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44062/how-do-i-install-lxde-lubuntu) or [XFCE/Xubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64241/how-do-i-switch-to-xubuntu).

I would also [mention MATE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87040/how-to-install-mate-in-11-10-and-above) that delivers much of the GTK+2 based libraries onto on Ubuntu.  If you take this option, you can use questions like *[how to remove unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6302/how-can-you-remove-unity)* to remove the GUI shell without touching the fundamental core of ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it is possible to completely uninstall Gnome 3 on 11.10 but you can install the Gnome 'Classic' session from the repositories which when selected at login will give you a close match to the Gnome 2 DE

Type the following in a terminal `sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback` then log out and select the Gnome Classic session at the log in manager.

There is a good guide to further customizing the appearance of it [here](http://mandriver.users.sourceforge.net/classic-gnome-guide.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can install MATE, a GNOME 2 fork, and uninstall Unity.
[Install MATE](http://www.noobslab.com/2011/11/install-linux-mint-mate-desktop-on.html)
[Remove Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6302/how-can-you-remove-unity)