# Will my all files be the same after updating from 10.04 to 12.04?

Tags: 10.04, 12.04

Programs like skype, browsers etc. etc. and my all files. Will it be the same after upgrading to 12.04 from 10.04 or I will have to reinstall everything? Thank you.

**EDIT:** Also, as I understood. only Unity is available in 12.04? Can I make it look like 10.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're doing an upgrade - your personal files, settings and applications you installed will be preserved, you won't have to reinstall them.

If you're doing a clean install then you will need to re-install applications.

In both cases it is advisable to make a full backup of your personal data.

Regarding Unity - Ubuntu 12.04 will include so-called "fallback mode" which is somewhat similar to Gnome 2, though it's not identical.

You can see a screenshot here: https://askubuntu.com/a/113991/14564

Comment: What about design? Only Unity is available in 12.04?

Comment: I updated the answer

Comment: I'd wait for the final release. It is scheduled for release in only 16 days.

Comment: @Jippie: definitely!