# How do I change the login manager in Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, login-screen

I've looked and looked for an answer - but I like Ubuntu's login manager, and can't figure out how to change lubuntu's to it.

I've installed Unity using these instructions: [How do I install LXDE / Lubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44062/how-do-i-install-lxde-lubuntu), but can't do that with the login window! Help, I'm a newbie!

P.S. I have Lubuntu installed on a USB key - hence, I don't want Ubuntu as the main install, but just for tinkering from time to time.

Comment: Also, if you want some pictures, check out [this WebUpD8 post](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/07/how-to-switch-between-gdm-lightdm-or.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can install it just by `sudo apt-get install lightdm lightdm-greeter-example-gtk`. In order to have a better view, have a look at [this wiki.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM)

Comment: Thank you! I saw that, but I it's still not working. If I use "sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm", nothing happens at all. If I try "sudo stop gdm", it says "unknown job: gdm". If I try "sudo start lightdm" is says "Job is already running."

Comment: Does it matter that I'm on 12.10?

Comment: When display manager comes up, press `Ctrl+Alt+F1` and try to kill it with `sudo killall gdm` (or any other display manager that you have). Then try to `sudo start lightdm`. let us know about the results

Comment: I can't even get to the display manager.