# How can I activate a Desktop Environment?

Tags: 12.04, installation, lxde, environment

Sorry if this is an incredibly stupid question, but I'm new to Linux on a whole & I'm trying hard to get into the flow with it. I recently installed LXDE which as you know is a DE, but I can't find any info on the net on how to activate it. Could anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Either of those should answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, both these answers give a good answer to your question:

1. [Switching window manager/desktop environments?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162516/switching-window-manager-desktop-environments/162518#162518)
2. [How do I install LXDE / Lubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44062/how-do-i-install-lxde-lubuntu)

But somehow they forget to mention that you must click on the small logo/circle which resides beside your username when starting your session. Something that you won't see if you have auto-login activated. So...

1.- If you write a password in order to start your Ubuntu session, simply click on the small icon (maybe a circle, an ubuntu logo or another thing depending on your current theme), and choose your desired Desktop environment from the list.

or...

2.- If you have auto-login activated, first close your current session in order to see the options mentioned on the step.

Good luck!