# How to speed up Ubuntu 14.04 in VirtualBox 4.3.10

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox

My virtualbox running ubuntu 14.04 but seep is very slow.

Virtualbox: 4.3.10
Ubuntu: 14.04
Virtualbox addon: 4.3.10

I have tried suggestion from post: [Why does a Ubuntu guest in VirtualBox run very, very slowly?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207813/why-does-a-ubuntu-guest-in-virtualbox-run-very-very-slowly?lq=1)

But doesn't work.

Comment: Finally I followed [@Gordon Glas]'s comments in post to install new virtualbox addon and issued fixed.
Steps I have done:
[0]/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
[1]sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential       
[2]Install addon [VBoxGuestAdditions_4.3.13-93885],https://www.virtualbox.org/download/testcase/VBoxGuestAdditions_4.3.13-93885.iso       
[3]/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p

Comment: Sorry but I think they are different. Because I still want to use Unity 3D GUI.

Comment: Only the last section on "GNOME flashback" of my answer there is a solution for people who's hardware is not capable of running Unity 3D. All other steps are for speeding up Unity3D.

Answer (score 2):

If your Ubuntu uses Unity, then it is natural Ubuntu runs very slow in Virtualbox. Ubuntu and Unity is very heavy, especially on low RAM. So the solution is vary, one of them is changing your Unity into another lightweigth user interface such as XFCE, LXDE, or even Openbox.

#### How To Install XFCE

[How can I install XFCE along side unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223536/how-can-i-install-xfce-along-side-unity)

#### How To Install LXDE

[How do I install LXDE / Lubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44062/how-do-i-install-lxde-lubuntu)

#### How To Install Openbox

http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-openbox-on-ubuntu-13-10-13-04-12-10-12-04-and-linux-mint-15-14-13/

The Google keyword for these is **how to install  ubuntu**.