# Unable to login to ubuntu 14.04 after upgrade from 12.04

Tags: 14.04

I upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 through update manager. However when I tried to log in through GUI the screen just freezes after accepting the credentials. The ~/.xsession-errors file output is http://paste.ubuntu.com/11915355/ . Tried installing compizconfig-settings-manager and then DISPLAY=:0 ccsm ..the unity plugin was already enabled. Switching back on tty1 it was stuck at "Loading icons..." . Then i tried unity --replace and then tried to go back to tty7 ..This time the desktop was visible alongwith the side laucher. However the top panel was missing (network,power,etc..) I tried a reboot ..again the problem repeated of freezing desktop.
I've been through the link: [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears) but the options don't seem to work.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Does the guest session login work?  It would have no old "dot" config files to confuse unity.

Comment: @ubfan1: no..same problem with the guest session too.

Comment: Were you running Unity 2D on the 12.04?  How much ram do you have?  Sometimes the switch to full unity in 14.04 breaks things.

Comment: yes..i had 2D running in it..I have 2GB ram on my system

Comment: Helo pranay, i had the same issue once. The problem could be that you have lost permission to your account(thought not sure about that, your problem is slightly diferent). But just to be sure please post, he outputs of following comands:   ls -al .Xauthority
ls -al .ICEauthority
ls -al /home

Comment: Xauthority : -rw------- 1 pranay pranay 65                                  ICEAuthority: -rwxrwx--- 1 - - 176906

Comment: the ls -al /home outputs this :http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/11918478/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your machine sounds pretty marginal for running unity.  I had similar problems with flickering windows and lockups on my old 2G max HP machine which I'd updated from 12.04 (2D unity) to 14.04.  After running OK for months, after an update, problems started -- I thought I'd fried the motherboard.
  I eventually installed Lubuntu, and it worked much better for me.  Backup all your files, and reinstall Lubuntu would be my suggested fix. I was also going around with Nvidia drivers, but they actually worked better than the nouveau in terms of overheating.

---

You can start with installing other desktops on your current Ubuntu, like xfce4, LXDE, etc. and choose them at the login (click on the Ubuntu icon in the corner of the login window).  To see if they help the problem. I did eventually remove unity and used xfce4, but also installed Lubuntu and found that setup was easier for me.

Comment: Thanks..i dont have any nvidia card in my sytem..Did you mean setting up the lububtu desktop as mentiined here :http://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=http://askubuntu.com/questions/44062/how-do-i-install-lxde-lubuntu&ei=A9iCQwo_&lc=en-IN&s=1&m=257&ts=1437541996&sig=AKQ9UO8hQXlawaMP4G_7uI9OCA5DQBjtGQ

Comment: LUbuntu did work..and i got back the desktop..On command line i did see that "Your hardware does not support Unity" ,wondering how it worked for 12.04