# Ubuntu 11.04 Launcher

Tags: 11.04, unity, launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I move the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33605/can-i-move-the-unity-launcher)

I have searched the net and found out that the Launcher is not movable. With widescreen format it makes perfect sense to have the launcher Vertically than horizontally. But, the folks at the Ubuntu developer community are left handed, I guess! The majority of the world works with right hand and thus I am stating to develop neck pain using the left aligned Launcher.

Now There is no-way to change it is a bit non sense as the OS is open source. There is definitely one gentleman who could release a patch to move the Launcher to the right.

Other than that it is making perfect sense.

Comment: And the question is? The options, basically, are: a. Open a bug report. Wait for the problem to be fixed; b. Fix the problem, submit a patch; c. Use something else

Comment: In 11.10 you can also not change it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Our sabdfl, [Mark Shuttleworth has spoken](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/668415/comments/2):

> I'm afraid that won't work with our broader design goals, so we won't
>   implement that.

There is a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/668415/) open for this already, status "wontfix"