# Is it possible to put unity on the bottom of your screen?

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I move the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33605/can-i-move-the-unity-launcher)

I would like to place unity bar at the bottom of my screen. Is this possible in 11.04?
If not will it be possible in 11.10 ubuntu version?