# When will I be able to move the Unity Sidebar?

Tags: unity, 11.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I move the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33605/can-i-move-the-unity-launcher)

I have an older desktop, that i really love, and it has a 4:3 screen, the kind i prefer. Quite frankly, the Unity sidebar is terrible on my screen. It looks great on my tiny netbook, and i love it there. But my desktop screen is large, and the unity sidebar sucks on it. if i could move it, i would be very happy. any idea when people will see sense and allow us to move it?