# How to set the configuration of taskbar?

Tags: taskbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I move the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33605/can-i-move-the-unity-launcher)

I want to change taskbar from left side to bottom, and I don't want it to be hide.

How to do that?