# moving the launcher "dock", I am confused

Tags: launcher, dock

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I move the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33605/can-i-move-the-unity-launcher)

I have spent the last 90 min searching i keep finding things saying it will not be supported other saying it is, some people saying a utility is around some place that lets you move it.

I just upgraded to 11.X I love it and think it is by far the best and most user friendly release this is one deal breaker for me.  I am a native mac person and used a "dock" application even before os X10.0 came out.

Sure some people love it on the left, me i am in PSD,IA,Gimp and inkscape 90% of my time and I am constantly opening up that menu when it is on the left.

Does any one know of this utility program people have talked about or a way to change it. I am on a project right now or i would spend the next 3 hours backing up and downgrading just so i can get work done with out cursing at my computer.

Thanks
Parabox1

Comment: are you asking if you can move the location of the launcher in 11.10 unity interface?  If so - the answer is no - it is designed that way.