# Can I change the launcher location?

Tags: unity, launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I move the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33605/can-i-move-the-unity-launcher)

I want to know if is possible, because I was looking for the settings but I did not find any.

Comment: Where would you like the dash moved to?!