# Unity launcher still unmovable in 5.0?

Tags: unity, 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I move the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33605/can-i-move-the-unity-launcher)

Is it possible to move the launcher from the left to any other place?

Comment: From the beggining this was not a planned feature the Launcher is going to stay there , because when the Ubuntu logo was in the top Panel the Launcher was supposed to go there to be as close as possible to it, but now that the logo is ON th eLauncher i see no point in having the Launcher in it's current position, but yes that's how it is supposed to be.