# How do I move the unity launcher to the bottom?

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I move the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33605/can-i-move-the-unity-launcher)

How do I move the unity launcher to the bottom