# Will Precise include an option to move the Unity Launcher?

Tags: unity, 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I move the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33605/can-i-move-the-unity-launcher)

Given that the community has created functionality to move the Unity launcher to the bottom of the screen, my question is whether or not Canonical will implement this in the default installation of ubuntu.

Originally, I know this wasn't intended, as Mark had said he wanted the launcher close to the ubuntu button, but now that the ubuntu button is on the launcher, have the UX issues surrounding this been resolved?