# Moving the Desktop Toolbar

Tags: gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I move the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33605/can-i-move-the-unity-launcher)

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 with Gnome.  I'm not sure what it's called, but the toolbar on the left hand screen that hides itself and contains icons for software updates and my home folder and such is in a really annoying place.  I'd like to move it to the bottom of the screen.  I've tried right clicking and dragging, but to no avail.  How do I do this?

Comment: ... if you are referring to the gnome-shell launcher then please flag for this to be reopened.  thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this link. I believe this is what you are looking for.

[Moving Unity Launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33605/can-i-move-the-unity-launcher)

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this with the new PPA that is available called Ubuntu Unity Bottom Launcher.  I will say this only works in Unity 3D so if your using Unity2D this will not work.  It also requires you to have compiz settings manager installed.

I have provided the following link that will show you how to install for there is too much to type on my own to describe.  Hope this helps

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/11/install-ubuntu-unity-bottom-launcher.html