# In terms of the desktop wall what is "edge flipping"?

Tags: unity, compiz, launcher, customization

I'm trying to make the launcher reveal on the bottom using Compiz, but everytime I change the reveal from left to bottom it says...

> The new value for the edge binding for the action Reveal Mode in plugin Ubuntu Unity Plugin conflicts with the action Flip Down of the Desktop Wall plugin.

If found the edge flipping settings in Compiz, but I don't want to change them if I don't know what it means.

Comment: Ultimately your question revolves around moving the Launcher panel to the bottom, so probably this question would help you? - [Can I move the Unity launcher?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/33605/can-i-move-the-unity-launcher)

Comment: @nitstorm:  That's just an asumption, far from a fact; it might just be that he has dual monitors, with the launcher between the monitors, making it hard to reveal, so he wants to use the bottom instead.  This is a problem some people have with dual monitors.

Comment: @MartyFried: Oh, wasn't sure of my assumption, so haven't voted to close it off yet :) Anyways, glad to know that such a condition exists. Thanks :)

Comment: @nitstorm: No problem; I happened to come across someone with this problem, and was trying to help find a solution; I had considered this as a possibility, but it didn't seem to work.  Also, it could be a solution for the problem where the panel keeps popping out when you overshoot trying to hit the back button on Firefox, which I've done many times.  I ended up setting the binding to only work in the corners, and not the edge.  But now I don't use Unity, partly due to Shuttleworth's insistence on not making the position an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edge flipping, which is disabled by default, I believe, allows you to move your mouse from one virtual desktop to another by simply moving past the edge.  It sort of treats it like it's one big desktop, in a way, except instead of smoothly scrolling, it flips by a full screen.  But it follows the cursor, so you don't need to move all the way across the screen to return to the previous desktop.

I personally find it very annoying, and I don't use it, but I'd guess it's probably better if you're used to it.  Maybe it's even handy, but I've never really tried.

If you don't have it enabled, it still has settings for where on the screen it's triggered, much like the setting for the reveal mode.  So, you might be able to safely ignore the warning.

Comment: Thanks for explaining what it is. So i should be able to change the reveal and not worry about the edge flipping?

Comment: Assuming you're not using edge flipping, it should be fine.  I don't think you'll need to disable the setting, since it's probably not even enabled, but if you don't use that feature, it's pretty easy to disable, then enable later if you want it.  It certainly won't hurt to disable it.