# Move unity launcher to another side of another screen

Tags: unity, launcher, multiple-monitors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I move the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33605/can-i-move-the-unity-launcher)

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 with 2 screens, 1 having resolution of 1366x768 and one with 1920x1080. As you could expect I'd prefer the larger one as the primary screen.

Smaller one is on the left and larger on the right. Due to the space available I cannot switch their places.

Now to my question.

This is how my screen looks now:
[image]

The small one is primary and larger one is secondary. So is it possible to move the launcher bar to the monitor on the right, and to the right side of that monitor, meaning as far away from the current position?

Thanks for help already in advance.

Comment: Third should be a case for xorg.conf but I'd recommend plugging reach monitor on the other plug.

Comment: dupe - http://askubuntu.com/q/33605/46312