# How do I move the Unity2D launcher to the right?

Tags: 11.10, unity-2d

I understand the [3D launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33605/can-i-move-the-unity-launcher) cannot be moved to the right.

Can the Unity2D Launcher be moved?

Answer (score 1):

Currently moving launcher to the right is impossible in both Unity 2D and 3D.
Keep your eye on the *Unity 2D Settings Tool* ([PPA](https://launchpad.net/~krytarik/+archive/tuxgarage)) as they plan to add this feature in the future.

Comment: So how can i cange it with the hebrew?