# How can I change my launcher location on the screen (left, right, bottom, top)?

Tags: launcher, 12.04, unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I move the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33605/can-i-move-the-unity-launcher)

I want to change where my launcher location is on the screen is. Do I have to install an application like *MyUnity* or can I just do it though the command line? I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 beta 1 for the record.