# Unity launcher on right side

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I move the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33605/can-i-move-the-unity-launcher)

Ok, I see there was a couple of posts asking to move unity to right side.  They were closed as they were considered and "exact duplicate" and no other info. One did have some other info, but was a thread talking about it being put to "another side of the screen", but in actuality was just talking about moving it to "the bottom" like windows.  That thread gave a somewhat reasonable rationality for not doing so as it was to save vertical real estate.  Moving it to the right however, does not violate this rationality.

There were others asking if it could be moved, and the answer was just a flat "No" or use something else.

So I'm going to post this asking *for the ability* to give the user the choice to have the unity launcher on the left or right.  And if not, why not.  Design decisions need to be backed up or they are meaningless and just get people upset.

Comment: adrianh, posts with exact duplicates do have links. Check for the "Possible Duplicates" header. As for the rest, your question is a feature request, which is not what AU is for. Check brainstorm.ubuntu.com.

Comment: Basically the answer is "no you cant" as per the linked duplicate.  The answers there already cover the reasons why you cannot move the launcher.  If you want a right-hand side launcher you need to choose a different desktop environment such as gnome-classic.