# How can I have two launchers, one on the left side of my left screen and on the right side of my right screen?

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors

With 12.04 and a dual monitor setup, I can choose to have the unity launcher only on the left screen or on the left side of both screens. Ideally, I would like to have a launcher on the left side of my left screen and on the right side of my right screen. Is this possible in Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no supported mechanism for doing this; the launcher is designed to be on the left-hand side of the screen.

Hacks like those seen [on this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33605/can-i-move-the-unity-launcher) might be developed (Unity *is* open source, after all), but I don't expect such a feature to be merged into mainline Unity.