# When will it be possible to move the Unity Launcher to the bottom of the screen (12.04)

Tags: unity, launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I move the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33605/can-i-move-the-unity-launcher)

After upgrading from 11.10 og 12.04, the possibility of moving the unity launcher to the bottom of the screen disappeared.

The measure to move the launcher in 11.10 was to install the Unity shell rotated plugin but it is not possible to install it in Ubuntu 12.04.

Any idea when this problem might be fixed?