# How to prevent Unity launcher appearing when using browser back button?

Tags: unity, launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I move the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33605/can-i-move-the-unity-launcher)

Try to use the back button on your browser and ever time you go up there launcher pops out and you have a battle to win against launcher so you can use your browser back button.

For example can the launcher be moved to anywhere but the left side of the screen?

Comment: You may want to re read several times this :http://askubuntu.com/questions/33605/can-i-move-the-unity-launcher?rq=1

Comment: If the launcher is popping up too easily, try changing the 'Reveal Sensitivity' in Settings → Apperance → Behaviour.

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate of the "reveal" question.  If you have a Thinkpad (or similar) laptop, with a dedicated "browser back" button, the Unity launcher annoyingly pops up every time you hit the browser back button.

Answer (score 2):

This is not directly related, but if you were having troubles hitting your back button I would suggest you right click and select the back option instead.  Usually this is the faster method any way.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can try editing unity's "Reveal Sensitivity"

Using details suggested by Jeremy in the comments, click on the Gear on the top right and use System Settings->Appearance->Behaviour Tab.

Answer (score 0):

The sensitivity setting is probably the best answer. But, in case it's helpfule:

Alt-Left Arrow can also be used to go back in your browser, if that's handy.