# What was the name of Mac bottom panel in Ubuntu?

Tags: gnome-panel

I forgot the name of the bottom panel like Mac in Ubuntu. What was it? I remember it was like Kiosk... But I couldn't reach any result by using this name.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple:

- [Avant Window Navigator/AWN](https://launchpad.net/awn/)

  [image: AWN Screenshot]
- [Docky](http://wiki.go-docky.com/index.php?title=Welcome_to_the_Docky_wiki)

  [image: Docky Screenshot]
- [Plank](http://wiki.go-docky.com/?title=Plank:Introduction)

  [image: Plank Screenshot]
- [DockbarX](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php?content=101604)

  [image: DockbarX Screenshot]

You can also use the XFCE4 Panel, using a tutorial I wrote previously: http://lkubuntu.wordpress.com/2011/09/04/make-xfce4-bottom-dock-act-like-docky-awn/
[image: XFCE4 Dock Screenshot]

Or you can also move the unity launcher to the bottom: [Can I move the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33605/can-i-move-the-unity-launcher)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look a cairo-dock.

> Cairo-Dock is an animated application launch bar for the desktop,
>   comparable to the dock in Mac OS X or Rocket Dock (for Windows).<sup>1</sup>

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[CairoDock](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CairoDock)</sup>

For more info click [Here](http://glx-dock.org/)

[image]