# How do I move the task bar back to the bottom where it belongs?

Tags: unity

How do I move the task bar back to the bottom of the screen where it belongs from it's stupid placement on the left.  I won't use Ubuntu as long as it has to be in the way where it is now.

Comment: "where it belongs". Says you. I say: left side is costing me the least amount of workspace so it suits fine on the left hand side.

Comment: try using kubuntu or xubuntu or lubuntu

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to move the 'task bar' to the bottom of the screen. You are out of luck.

Comment: Here is the Way to Move the Taksbar to bottom
http://askubuntu.com/questions/33605/can-i-move-the-unity-launcher

Comment: @ Babin lonston - This is for an old version (11.x) and as stated in that thread there is no way to do this in a up-to-date version.

Answer (score 0):

Before you log in, click the little circle to the upper right of your name, then select a different window manager that works more like Windows instead. You might like Cinnamon (or maybe gnome). This will get you the taskbar on the bottom that you want.

Comment: Don't forget to install the associated desktop first. I don't think it is installed by default.