# How to move taskbar to bottom position as in Windows

Tags: 14.04, taskbar

I'm very new to Ubuntu. I have just installed it on my pc and i liked it. But as i'm from Windows background i like the taskbar at the bottom and not at the left position. So is there any way to move it to bottom position? I searched on the net and found a solution but it is for 32 bit version 11.10 and i'm using version 14.04 LTS the latest one on 64 bit machine. Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: Hmm... seems like you asking separate things... are you talking about the `launcher` at the left side? Or the `panel` at the top of the screen?

Comment: If you're wanting to move the launcher to the bottom, there's no official support for that since 12.04. But there are third-party workarounds. Look at this [answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/33605/can-i-move-the-unity-launcher/72801#72801), and there is also a search function on this site as well as using google itself

Comment: @ElefantPhace:- I'm asking about the launcher which is at the left position as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: ok... well then read my comment above and proceed as you wish

Comment: Check this out, it worked for me.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/33605/can-i-move-the-unity-launcher

Comment: Check out this link ['Launcher Position'](http://www.howtogeek.com/202708/how-to-convert-the-unity-launcher-into-a-dock-style-launcher/), it's very simple article.

Comment: Upgrade to 16.04 , that feature is available in 16.04 but not in 14.04

Answer (score 16):

I know this question is for 14.04, but as this is one of the first results for "moving taksbar to bottom", I think it will be helpful to others like me who want to do this on **Ubuntu 16.04**:

Just execute the following command:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher launcher-position Bottom
```

Or, if you prefer something more detailed, and more options, install **unity tweak tool**, as explained in the accepted answer.

Comment: no such key 'launcher position in 14.04

Comment: This is it. This is what you should use with 16.04+. It also works on 17

Comment: No such schema “com.canonical.Unity.Launcher” in 19.10

Answer (score 9):

In case you want to use unity you can achieve similar thing:

1. Install unity-tweak-tool:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
   ```
2. Run `unity-tweak-tool` and in Launcher choose autohide.
3. Install cairo-dock using:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install cairo-dock
   ```
4. Run cairo-dock and add the applications in the dock you wanna use.

In case you wanna use gnome you can use gnome-session-flashback and delete the taskbar above and you can achieve desired functionality:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-flashback
```

You can refer complete tutorial on:

http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/how-to-install-and-tweak-gnome.html

Comment: This adds a Mac OS-like task bar at the bottom, but also keeps the Unity system tray thing (it doesn't show any tasks) at the top. The taskbar is such a basic and fundamental UI element for any OS. I'm amazed at how impossible it is to configure it in Unity vs. *cough* Windows.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using XFCE, you simply right click the panel -> Panel preferences. Then drag it whereever you like. Like so:

[image: Move that taskbar]

Comment: This works the best. This is what I did as well.

Answer (score 4):

- Go to ‘System Settings > Appearance’
- Select the ‘Behavior’ tab
- Find the section headed: ‘Show the Menus for a Window’
- Check (click) the circle next to ‘In the window’s title bar’

Comment: This most definitely does *not* answer the question, but I still like this change too! Thanks for the tip!

Comment: 6 years later and still helping people, thank you

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are using the main edition of Ubuntu 14.04 x64. Unfortunately the desktop environment of main edition called **Unity** lacks any ability of customization - you can't move anything.

You can try installing other desktop environments such as **Xfce**. You can read how to install Xfce in your Ubuntu 14.04 in [this site](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/alternative). In Xfce you can move "panels" (taskbars) to either top or bottom of the screen and you can also customize the contents (applets) of the taskbar.

Answer (score 1):

Use *Just Perfection* extension (https://extensions.gnome.org//extension/3843/just-perfection/)

Answer (score 0):

In Pop OS, I needed to:

- press win key, type 'settings'
- go to 'System Settings > Desktop > Dock'

Answer (score -1):

if you click on panel preferences (right click), you can move the panel whilst in this mode (on my computer it is highlighted with a red dashed border). The icons don't line up but its better then before. You also delete the panel, by using the plus or minus on the panel preferences pane.

Comment: Context: This is only available on XFCE, not the default Ubuntu Desktop.