# Move the launcher to bottom in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, launcher

I am not familiar with the Ubuntu 14.04 and am also trying Ubuntu for the first time. Is there any way to move the launcher to the bottom or right or top?

Comment: any where except left side?? o.O

Comment: Solution seems to be here http://askubuntu.com/questions/33605/can-i-move-the-unity-launcher

Comment: @KasiyA the posted answer is not for 14.04 (I guess).Is there any updated answers

Comment: Try this http://www.ubuntulinuxguide.com/how-to-move-the-unity-launcher/