# How to change unity side laucher position from left to right ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, unity, launcher

Is there any method available using which we can change the position of side bar laucher from left to right. I have installed the unity tweak tool but it only allows to auto hide the launcher. There are many tutorials which teaches about how to move launcher to the bottom but i am unable to find any links pertaining the position change to the right
[image]

P.S. not to confuse with any other launcher i am uploading this picture

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/33605/can-i-move-the-unity-launcher

Comment: I want launcher to move to right and not to the bottom

Comment: WH@, I can't position the launcher?  That's some sloppy design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot move the launcher itself.

[Here is the comment on a bug about it](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/668415/comments/2)

But you can make it look like with ***Cairo dock***.

```
sudo apt-get install cairo-dock
```

Now you can play around with configurations and move the dock to the right.

[image]

Make Unity's launcher auto-hide and you have a launcher (*actually not launcher, it is dock* ) on the right.

[image]

I like Ubuntu for its customizability. Do you?

Comment: Not being able to do something as basic as moving the default launcher to the right shows lack of customizability, not the opposite. Thanks for this workaround though

Comment: @FranciscoH. **Ubuntu has lots of customizations**.  You can **easily** change desktops as well as application launchers.  Unity is new and can be dropped as a preference.  Unity has its problems as in this case.  But it's not forced on the Ubuntu users.  I have the same grip as you see with Unity, but my grip is with **Nautilus**'s lack of features.  So I custimize my Ubuntu to use **Nemo** instead.  Muzaffar, **Yes! Me too.  I like Ubuntu for its customizations.**