# Pin Apps to Desktop layout

Tags: pinning

Noobie, Using Ubuntu v. 15.04---Three part question:

1. I am trying to pin an app or program to the desktop workspace, rather than clogging the "launcher" sidebar. In fact, the Launcher sidebar is so loaded with apps I have to stream down through all the cramped apps located there just to check the one I'd like. Every app I like goes automatically to the sidebar one installed. I have "created new (empty) folders" on the desktop (for Finance/Documents/Business/Legal etc.), and even pinned Firefox (via right-click context menu). I just would like to  access files or apps in a desktop folder vs. from a string of apps along the sidebar...
2. In fact, can I drag and drop apps from the Launcher sidebar directly ONTO the desktop?? (I tried = no joy)...I like a drag and drop function...
3. Can I place the Launcher along the bottom of the desktop versus left sidebar?

Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

1. Drag your apps from Dash Menu instead of dragging them from launcher.
2. Once you have pinned them to the desktop, usually they will be able to launch. Otherwise wou will have to give them special permission for that.

Open the terminal: `Ctrl+Alt+T`

Run the command:

```
sudo chmod +x ~/Desktop/*.desktop
```

Next run the command below:

```
sudo chown (your user name) ~/Desktop/*.desktop
```

Read here for info: [How to make shortcuts for apps](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/04/add-application-shortcuts-to-your-desktop-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/)

3. No, you can't move the launcher to the bottom. Instead you can use Cairo-Dock or Docky software to imitate the launcher.

See answers here: [How to change unity side laucher position from left to right ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/599113/how-to-change-unity-side-laucher-position-from-left-to-right-ubuntu-14-04/599154#599154) and here: [Can I move the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33605/can-i-move-the-unity-launcher)

Comment: where exactly is "Dash Menu?" ("Search Computer?" Ubuntu Software Center?)...will try Terminal (so unnecessary in a DOS-like command setup---should be PNP or GUI)...will review your links as well  Thx

Comment: found Dash (search computer, first upper left icon), tried to drag an app, no joy, flipped right back into dash menu...will try "permissions" next.

Comment: It should drag and drap without any problems even if you don't specify permissions.

Answer (score 1):

1. There's a folder `/usr/share/applications` where all the shortcuts are stored - copy whichever you want to respective directories on your desktop;
2. No
3. That will require a dock app, such as plank (my favorite) or cairo-dock

Comment: Thanks Serg...I tried Cairo-dock, but it disappeared on reboot. What I think I will also do is search the usr/share file,  see what's there, then delete many of the apps in the Launcher bar. As you can probably guess, I am from Windows 7 (hate Windows privacy) but it's a little hard & frustrating adapting to the directory trees and names in Linux.

Comment: @Doc Um . . .it's probably one of those apps that needs to be added to autostart entries; don't remember exactly if that's so:  I've tried it long ago in 13.04 and didn't like it, so haven't continued using it.

Comment: Serg, located file folder, tried drag/drop, failed, says I need permission. I will also try Plank app. Thx

Comment: Yeah, that folder is owned by root user. Um....are you ok with using terminal for just a little bit ?

Comment: Also, try copying, not drag and drop.