# Multiple monitors in Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu

I have two monitors on my computer and the right hand monitor is the main display, but Lubuntu always puts the main display onto the left hand monitor. There aren't enough settings in the Monitor Settings window to change the main display onto the right hand monitor. How do I do this? I have Mint on some other computers and this is easy with their tools so it must be supported in the underlying X server? I have an AMD graphics card with the default driver.

Also is it possible in LXDE to have panels on both monitors instead of just the main display monitor?

Comment: Please add the output of xrandr to the question, and indicate which monitor you'd like on the right side.

Comment: Also what version of lubuntu is this? Lubuntu 15.10 and later have new settings in monitor settings and will be in the soon to be released next LTS 16.04 but these options are not present in 14.04

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I move the Unity launcher?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/33605/can-i-move-the-unity-launcher)

Answer (score 5):

Install `arandr` from the repos and you'll have a GUI to configure the multiple monitors. I don't know about the panel part of the question.

Answer (score 3):

To establish dual monitors with LXDE, install Arandr from Synaptics. Arandr can set-up placement, orientation and resolution for each monitor. Before saving, set up the geometry of any horizontal panels. For a bottom panel across both monitors, align the bottoms of the displays; for a top panel, align the tops. A second horizontal panel can be only set-up on the display whose unaligned edge is outermost, since any extension onto the smaller display will be hidden. Otherwise, the horizontal placement and geometry in general can be achieved in the usual way.  See http://lxlinux.com/#14 for more details.