# Move the launcher to the right hand side?

Tags: 16.04, launcher

I am running ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I'd love to have the launcher on the right hand side, as it is much more convenient, considering the way my monitors are set up.

I know it can be moved to the bottom, but I already have a dock there that I like. It would be more useful to me on the right hand side.

Is there a way to do this?

Currently, I can't find a way to do it. I have checked this and many other forums.

Comment: This may help: [Can I move the unity launcher?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/33605/can-i-move-the-unity-launcher)

Answer (score 3):

No, thats not possible with Unity. Canonical did hardcode the position of the buttons on the Unity plugn, and there is still no way to change that.

If you really want to have the panel on your right hand side I'd recommend you to change to another desktop as the classic Gnome or also named `Gnome Flashback` :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-flashback
```

Once installed, log off and change the desktop by clicking on the Ubuntu icon next to your login name and choose "Gnome Flashback".

I recommend you to try it and customize it at your will, as you can always go back to Unity by simply selecting it again the same way I just explained.