# Gnome 3 settings fail to apply on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-gnome, system-settings, gnome-control-center

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 17.04 on a Razer Blade (2016). After installation I installed `nvidia-375`, `nvidia-prime`, `gnome-shell`, and `ubuntu-gnome-desktop`. This is otherwise a pristine install.

However, I have two "settings" apps, one that corresponds to `ubuntu-system-settings`, and one that corresponds to `gnome-control-center`. The `gnome-control-center` settings app looks like the default ubuntu settings app, but its contents have changed somewhat.

The `ubuntu-system-settings` app is the only one that contains options to modify the app launcher on the desktop. However, none of the changes I make to the settings in `ubuntu-system-settings` app every take effect.

What should I do to A) configure my system so that there is one settings panel (if that is the right thing to do), and more importantly B) grant myself the ability to modify settings for things like the app launcher?

[image]

Comment: `modify the app launcher` ... what modification are you talking about? Its position or something else?

Comment: Is it what you're trying to do? https://askubuntu.com/questions/33605/can-i-move-the-unity-launcher

Comment: In the image you can see options to "always show the launcher" and to adjust the size of its icons. I would like to do that.

Comment: So, it doesn't appear on Unity session or GNOME session. I'm assuming you've both sessions.

Comment: Yes, I didn't delete unity, but I don't expect they are running simultaneously.